# A hook (`orm`) failed to load while using sails-mongo in sails version 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Sails Version: `1.2.3`
Node Version: `v10.14.2`
Sails Mongo Version: `1.0.1`

Datastore configuration:

```
default: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url:
      'mongodb://user:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/user_db'
```

> The password consists of special character like `#!_-`. Is that the
>   problem?
>
> For some reasons, even after change of password with special
>   characters to the appropriate one, still it's not able to connect.

I look forward assistance on connection to establish using localhost as well without username and password. How to construct such connection string?

````
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Consistency violation: Attempting to tear down a datastore (`default`) which is not currently registered with this adapter.  This is usually due to a race condition in userland code (e.g. attempting to tear down the same ORM instance more than once), or it could be due to a bug in this adapter.  (If you get stumped, reach out at http://sailsjs.com/support.)
    at Object.teardown (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/index.js:390:19)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:758:27
    at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3047:20
    at eachOfArrayLike (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1002:13)
    at eachOf (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1052:9)
    at Object.eachLimit (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3111:7)
    at Object.teardown (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:742:11)
    at Hook.teardown (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/index.js:246:30)
    at Sails.wrapper (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Sails.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Sails.emitter.emit (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/after.js:56:26)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:67:11
    at beforeShutdown (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:45:12)
    at Sails.lower (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:49:3)
    at Sails.wrapper [as lower] (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
error: Failed to lift app: Error: Consistency violation: Unexpected error creating db connection manager:
```
MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at flaverr (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/flaverr/index.js:94:15)
    at Function.module.exports.parseError (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/flaverr/index.js:371:12)
    at Function.handlerCbs.error (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:665:56)
    at connectCb (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/create-manager.js:130:22)
    at connectCallback (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:428:5)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:376:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```
    at Object.error (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/index.js:268:21)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1514:39
    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:1153:14)
    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:913:12)
    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:845:10)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:303:7
    at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:952:35
    at Function.handlerCbs.error (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:742:26)
    at connectCb (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/create-manager.js:130:22)
    at connectCallback (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:428:5)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/ozone-login-system/node_modules/mongodb/lsib/mongo_client.js:376:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
````

Answer (score 0):

I am using mongo altas for learning the following worked for me

```
adapter: require('sails-mongo'),
    url: 'mongodb://dbUser:dbpass@learning-cluster-shard-XXXXXXXXXXX',
  },
```

If you are using atlas, don't forget to allow access to your current IP on mongo atlas website

Answer (score 0):

If you're viewing this in 2020, you need to use the older mongo-db url settings to connect mongo Atlas to sails.

```js
//config/datastores.js
default:
  { adapter: require('sails-mongo'),
    url: "mongodb://<YOUR_USERNAME>:<YOUR_PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00-kiodk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-kiodk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-kiodk.mongodb.net:27017/<YOUR_DB_NAME>?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority",
  }
```

For it to work with sails, your URL should be in the format above!